# Why is QueryParameter not picked up?

Tags: java, servlets, jenkins-plugins

I am writing a plugin for Jenkins. It exposes an endpoint under yourjenkins.link/custom-api/. The method:

```
@GET
@WebMethod(name = "logs1")
public HttpResponse logs1(StaplerRequest req,
                          @QueryParameter(required = true) String jobName,
                          @QueryParameter(required = true) String buildNumberString) throws IOException {
```

is accessible under: yourjenkins.link/custom-api/logs1.

The problem is that when I try:
`curl -H "Blah: blah" http://localhost:8080/jenkins/custom-api/logs1?jobName=test&buildNumberString=48 -v`
I get:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Required Query parameter buildNumberString is missing
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.QueryParameter$HandlerImpl.parse(QueryParameter.java:71)
```

The query parameter from org.kohsuke.stapler package seems to work only with one parameter. How can I use both parameters?

PS: I don't want to get them from the request body as the method should be called only when the request type is GET.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was not in the actual function, but rather the curl command. It included the '&' sign which was breaking it.